# SignalR send duplicate message to same user n times n is number of users connected .NetCore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr, sqldependency

I have SignalR ASP.NET Core project and trying to send message tp specific user which I manage to do so. The problem is same message send `n` time  `n=number` of tabs or connections when ever there is change from database it send notification to that certain User but duplicate the message.

```cs
public class MessageHub: Hub
{       
    public MessageHub(IConfiguration cc, IHubContext<MessageHub> _mess, UserManager<ApplicationUser> rep)
    {
        mess = _mess;
        _conf = cc;
        _usermanager = rep;
        RegisterNotification();
    }

    public void RegisterNotification()
    {        
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCommand, con);

            if (con.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Open();
            }

            cmd.Notification = null;
        
            SqlDependency sqlDep = new SqlDependency(cmd);
          
            sqlDep.OnChange += sqlDep_OnChange;
          
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                // nothing need to add here now
            }
        }
    }

    static int count = 1;
    private  void sqlDep_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change )
        {
            SqlDependency sqlDep = sender as SqlDependency;
            sqlDep.OnChange -= sqlDep_OnChange;
                      
            mess.Clients.User("64ed09d7-255f-4aae-a25f-7a50e59943b4").SendAsync("abc", "hello"+count);
            count += 1;

           RegisterNotification();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: User and connection are different concepts. Single user can have multiple connection to SignalR server, and when you send message to specific user with Clients.User("SomeUserId").SendAsync("SomeData") message is sent to all active connections. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.ihubclients-1.user?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_SignalR_IHubClients_1_User_System_String_

Comment: thank you  but  how to send message to single user with IHubContext

Comment: I think the problem is Register notification  that add SqlDependency each time user connected to hub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you have mentioned, the problem is `RegisterNotification` is being called everytime an instance of `MessageHub` is created. Instead of this, you can create background service and register to `SqlDependency` there and send the events using `IHubContext`. And after every notification, you call `RegisterNotification` again, which might cause the duplication as well.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext

I haven't tested this code, but here is an example:

```cs
public class EventBroadcaster : IHostedService
{
    private readonly IHubContext<MessageHub> _hubContext;
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public EventBroadcaster(
           IConfiguration configuration, 
           IHubContext<MessageHub> hubContext)
    {
         _hubContext = hubContext;
         _connectionString = // Get Connection String from configuration
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Started event broadcasting service");

        RegisterNotification();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }


    public void RegisterNotification()
    {        
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCommand, con);

            if (con.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Open();
            }

            cmd.Notification = null;
        
            SqlDependency sqlDep = new SqlDependency(cmd);
          
            sqlDep.OnChange += sqlDep_OnChange;
          
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                // nothing need to add here now
            }
        }
    }

    static int count = 1;
    private async void sqlDep_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change )
        {
            SqlDependency sqlDep = sender as SqlDependency;
            sqlDep.OnChange -= sqlDep_OnChange;
                      
            await _hubContext.Clients.User("64ed09d7-255f-4aae-a25f-7a50e59943b4").SendAsync("abc", "hello"+count);

            count += 1;
        }
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Event Broadcasting Service is stopping.");

        // TODO: Stop listening to SqlDependency notifications

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

Comment: It worked like charm .. galak swpastan akam

Comment: What is necessary to get the OnChange event to fire when the db updates. I'm running this in Net 5 and it never fires. Set it up just like your example.